# Halcon - Extract straight edge from XLD

Tags: line, extract, feature-extraction, halcon

I have a XLD edge, like the one in red in the sample picture below.

I need to extract start/endpoint of straight lines that reppresent it. Hough lines sort of work for this, but the results are not really replicable. minor changes in the contour produce unexpected results.

How can the contours be extracted as straight lines? (blue) with start and finish coordinates?
lines shorter than a specified length should not be counted as separate line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contour needs to be converted to a polygon using the following function:

```
gen_polygons_xld (Object, Polygons, 'ramer', 25.0)
```

The only adjustable parameter is the alpha (25.0) which decides the approximation threshold.

[image]

Comment: thanks.. but i already have the controur in XLD format. (represented by the red line). what I need is to have straight  lines instead of the many little lines. so my XLD is the red line, i would need to transform it into the blue lines.

Comment: Could you upload the .xld file?

Comment: sure! here is the file with the contour: igormasin.it/fileuploads/SelectedXLD.hobj

Comment: thank you.. its not exactly as I need it, sicne i need one line per edge, but its close enough.. thank you very much!